# Is thrift a messaging queue? How thrift is different from typical messaging systems?

Tags: messaging, message-queue, thrift

If i serialize my messages on one machine using thrift and deserialize on another, how do i know that my messages will reach in same order? And since from first machine i am sending messages continuously, if second machine is not able to consume messages at same speed where will my messages be buffered?

Does thrift act like messaging queue? What is the difference between thrift and messaging systems?

Answer (score 3):

Thrift is not a message queue, and it does not act like one. Thrift is kind of RPC (remote procedure call).

In most common scenarios, the calls client makes are transferred over the TCP connection, and they are ordered by underlying TCP connection.

If you are using HTTP transport for Thrift, then some calls can reach server out of order.

Comment: So, machine which is serializing the message will communicate with thrift server and deserializer machine will have thrift client? Where are serialized messages stored on thrift server?

Comment: First they are not messages they are remote procedure calls, and they are not stored on the server.